# Changing the Default Placement of Matplotlib Subplots

Tags: matplotlib, subplot

I am making arrays of subplots (various sizes of arrays, but all of the subplots are the same size), and I would like to specify that the subplots "fill in" (get placed in the total plot) in a bottom-up order rather than top-down.

That is, rather than starting the placement of the plots from the top left corner, filling that row, and starting the next row below the first subplot, I would rather the placement begin from the bottom left corner, fill the row, and start the next row above the first subplot.

Is there a way to do this?  I couldn't find any documentation that did precisely this.

Answer (score 1):

You could always change the array of axes after it's created, e.g.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
f, axes = plt.subplots(2, 2)
axes = axes[(1, 0), :]

for ax, color in zip(axes.flat, "rgbc"):
    ax.plot([0, 1], [0, 1], color)
```

[image]

I am not aware of a keyword in `plt.subplots` that does this, though.